# Replication group replicates complete database cross region in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have a snowflake accounts in AWS_US_EAST_1 and AWS_US_WEST_2. Im trying to use replication group to replicate some objects from AWS_US_EAST_1  to AWS_US_WEST_2 account. Problem is that replication group replicates complete database even when I grant privilege on only one table in allowed shares.

Is there any solution to replicate only few tables from database across regions in snowflake?

Created replication group but it replicates complete database.

Replication Group CREATE statement:

```
CREATE REPLICATION GROUP rep_cross_gp1 
OBJECT_TYPES = DATABASES, SHARES 
ALLOWED_DATABASES = PRIVATE_DB 
ALLOWED_SHARES = ds2_ds1 
ALLOWED_ACCOUNTS = xyz ;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the config of your replication group. If you set up a share, add only the tables you want to it and then add the share to the RG then that should work. If you haven't added the database to either the share or the RG I'm not sure how it could be replicated

Comment: I've done all that . CREATE REPLICATION GROUP rep_cross_gp1
    OBJECT_TYPES = DATABASES, SHARES
    ALLOWED_DATABASES = PRIVATE_DB
    ALLOWED_SHARES = ds2_ds1
    ALLOWED_ACCOUNTS = xyz
    ;here share ds2_ds1 only has access to one table

Comment: So which DB is being replicated? If it's PRIVATE_DB then that's because you've included it the list of ALLOWED_DATABASES

Comment: I want to replicate only private_db.table1 instead of all database tables. so should I not allow this database?

Comment: Correct - only include the objects you actually want to replicate. In your case it would be a share containing the table

Comment: No , it replicates the actual share, its a share itself (no data) . I want to replicate only one table from private_db . I think replication_filter is the only way to do it. Do you have any idea how this can be applied?

Comment: If you read the documentation you can see the types of objects that can be replicated and this does not include standalone tables: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-replication-group. If you want to replicate a single table then you would need to create a share specifically for this purpose, add the table to the share and replicate the share

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a database with only objects to want to replicate in your Primary account.